# Can I control how google accounts get synced? Mobile vs Wifi

Tags: sync, google-play-music, mobile-data, google-plus-photos

Under Settings>Accounts>Google>(my account) there is a bunch of services you can check and uncheck.

My question specifically is I'd like everything to be synced but I want to be able to choose which services sync over wifi or mobile data.

For example, I'd like most services to sync on both wifi and data but I want music and g+ photos to sync only when on wifi. Is there a way to do this?

I also don't want to disable auto sync.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syncing Google Play Music doesn't actually download the music: it just updates the list of what music you have. Music streams, caches, or downloads when you start to play it, and you can control that using the settings inside Google Play Music itself: **Download via Wi-Fi only** and **Stream via Wi-Fi only**.

In the same way, you can control when Google+ "Auto-Backup" backs up photos and videos, using the settings inside Google+. From the settings menu, click **Auto-Backup**, and click **Back up photos** and **Back up videos** to select when they're synced.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Tasker automate with Synker apps on Google play store. After installed them create a new profile "State>Net>WiFi connected".

Next it request to create a new task. Go to"New task>plugin>synker auto sync". Next tap its configuration button and choose required sync options.

Next create a tasker exit task. In this task create "disable auto sync". Then, whenever your device disconnected from any WiFi it will disable auto sync. It's a battery friendly.

Save the profile.

Like wise create another profile with new task for mobile data connection.